# How to block IP addresses in HAProxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy, deny

Is there something like Apache "deny from ip" in haproxy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can drop an IP at the tcp level by creating an ACL and then using connection reject if the ACL is matched:

```
    acl bad_ip src 10.10.10.0
    tcp-request connection reject if bad_ip
```

You could also set up a 403 backend and send them to that if you want to do it at the HTTP level:

```
frontend foo
        ...
        acl bad_ip src 10.10.10.0
        use_backend bad_guy if bad_ip
...

backend bad_guy
        mode http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
```

These ACLs can be pretty flexible, and you can make it so multiple conditions within an ACL, or multiple ACLs within the action have to be met. More at http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt .

Comment: You only need a separate backend if you want to use a custom 403 error page. Otherwise, you can get away with "http-request deny if bad_ip"

Comment: Do you know of way to read the ips from a more flexible store, like db or seperate flat file?

Comment: That backend bad_guy doesn't work as expected, since it has no defined servers, it is considered "down" and will always return 503 - service not available. I just fould you can just write "block if bad_ip" to frontend configuration and it will throw 403 page properly. EDIT: http-request deny if bad_ip works as advertised by @sh-beta - essentially does the same thing, but maybe just for http requests?

Comment: There is another slight difference between block and http-request deny and that's this: "a 'block' rule placed after a 'use_backend' rule will still be processed before."

Comment: If you give a "bad" guy a 403 then he knows that he is blocked and will look for another Vector. If you give a "bad" guy a 503 ..hen he thinks he successfully caused a DOS and stops the attack.. Course he may figure it out but it will take him a lot longer.

Comment: How can that be used for many ips? Is it just a comma list?

Comment: @IanVaughan you can use the following `acl bad_list  src -f /etc/haproxy/some-file-with-ips.list
tcp-request connection reject if bad_list